# How to cross check Data Types in C?

Tags: c

I have been wondering how computers get an input for given data type. I want to know what type of data type the user entered, example, whether the given input is char or integer or float or double, all specific. If the input is `a`, it should tell it is a character, if `123` it should tell it is an integer, if `12.1` then it is `float`, if `12.001` then it is `double` type. Can any C code function go for this?

C coding, a function to return the right datatype of the given single input. Also, help me to get those input with the help of `scanf()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-stratch_ coding service here. :-)

Comment: You just need to fetch a string with `scanf` and then parse it to see what would be it's best representation. The parsing in this case is very simple, just try to convert it from the least obvious possible type to the least, the least being of course text.

Comment: thankyou.Im,going to declare a string and parse it with character or ASCI code for numbers using if() statement, then if it is number,i wil convert char no.to int no.Then using a for()loop i can get exact conversion of string 123 to integer 1*100+2*10+3,THEN if string contains character '.' then i will make necessary to convert the hole term to a double, like string 123.2 wil becom double 123.2000 den i check whether it fits float or int, like if(double(int(123.000))=123.000) then its an integer data type. if( double(int(123.100))=123.1000) then it fits with float datatype. else () its double.

Comment: In case of character parsing will reveal. thus i can make run my program differently to different datatype entered by the user. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no C function to do that.

Consider that C is statically typed, there's no built-in way to have a single variable hold a value which has one of many different actual types like you describe. So even if there was a function `magicparse()`, what type would you expect it to return?

Also, of course `123.001` is not necessarily `double`, you're just making up rules and expecting the standard library to know in advance and have a compliant function?

Waht you need to do, yourself, is to read a string from the user (typically using `fgets()` to read a whole line in a safe manner), then write code to inspect ("parse") that string, and *decide* what datatype you think the user meant. Do do that you must invent some rules, for instance note how C lets you type `foo(12)` to pass an integer, while `foo(12.0f)` passes a `float` and `foo(12.0)` passes a `double` these rules are part of the language, but you need to make up your own.

Comment: However it's perfectly possible to implement a `struct value_variant{enum{T_INT, T_DBL, T_CHR}type; union{int i; unsigned int ui; double dbl;}value;};` and write a parser the determines the best matching type and returns that structure. Strings of course are a different beast.

Comment: Hats off. thank you. Im not knowing how to get an input, in scanf() statement what should i need to code %c or %d or %f. The program works different manner for different datatype entered. so in which datatype should i need to get in scanf() statement?

Comment: im going to declare a string and parse it with character or ASCI code for numbers using if() statement, then if it is number,i wil convert char no.to int no.Then using a for()loop i can get exact conversion of string 123 to integer 1*100+2*10+3,THEN if string contains character '.' then i will make necessary to convert the hole term to a double, like string 123.2 wil becom double 123.2000 den i check whether it fits float or int, like if(double(int(123.000))=123.000) then its an integer data type. if( double(int(123.100))=123.1000) then it fits with float datatype. else () its double.

Comment: In case of character parsing will reveal. thus i can make run my program differently to different datatype entered by the user. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge there is no function which returns the type of data type you are using. Instead of finding the data type you can estimate it by using the inbuilt function called sizeof() which gives the size of the data from which you can estimate the data type.

Comment: fuction is not possible.. But we can take user input in char[] array and phase it with type.. like no. with no '.' is an integer.., with '.' then float.., if char only then string.. thats it.. i will soon post coding.. im done but bluestack stops me to share...

Answer (score -1):

There is a big hint at the end of the question: you can use `scanf()` for this.

To parse input whose type is unknown, you should read it as a string of characters and try and parse it with different methods.  Note that the set of values representable as `double` and `float` overlap: it is a matter of convention whether `12.1` is to be considered a `float` or a `double`. Neither type actually represents this value precisely.  In C source code, a suffix `f` or `F` is used to tell the compiler the value is a `float` as opposed to a `double` (or an integer if is does not have a decimal point nor an exponent).

Here is a small function to test and parse these types:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char *tell_type(void) {
    char buf[128];
    float f;
    double d;
    int i;
    int n;

    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        return "EOF";
    }
    if (sscanf(buf, "%i%n", &i, &n) == 1) {
        if (buf[i] == '\0' || isspace((unsigned char)buf[i])
            return "integer";
    }
    if (sscanf(buf, "%lf%n", &d, &n) == 1) {
        if (buf[n] == 's' || buf[n] == 'S')
            return "float";
        else
            return "double";
    }
    return "char";
}
```